# why does batch normalization make my batches so abnormal?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, batch-normalization

I'm playing with pytorch for the first time, and I've noticed that when training my neural net, about one time in four or so the loss takes a left turn towards infinity, then nan shortly after that. I've seen a few other questions about nan-ing, but the recommendations there seem to be essentially to do normalization; but the first layer in my net below is such a normalization, and I still see this problem! The full net is [a bit convoluted](https://github.com/dmwit/nurse-sveta/blob/803b0a2a17c5d82454a0765e300c440d6e5f1f5e/nsaid/nsaid/__main__.py), but I've done some debugging to try to produce a very small, understandable net that still displays the same issue.

The code is below; it consists of sixteen inputs, 0-1, which are passed through a batch normalization and then a fully-connected layer to a single output. I'd like it to learn the function that always outputs 1, so I take the squared error from 1 for the loss.

```
import torch as t
import torch.nn as tn
import torch.optim as to

if __name__ == '__main__':
    board = t.rand([1,1,1,16])
    net = tn.Sequential \
        ( tn.BatchNorm2d(1)
        , tn.Conv2d(1, 1, [1,16])
        )
    optimizer = to.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.1)
    for i in range(10):
        net.zero_grad()
        nn_outputs = net.forward(board)
        loss = t.sum((nn_outputs - 1)**2)
        print(i, nn_outputs, loss)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

If you run it a few times, eventually you'll see a run that looks like this:

```
0 tensor([[[[-0.7594]]]], grad_fn=<MkldnnConvolutionBackward>) tensor(3.0953, grad_fn=<SumBackward0>)
1 tensor([[[[4.0954]]]], grad_fn=<MkldnnConvolutionBackward>) tensor(9.5812, grad_fn=<SumBackward0>)
2 tensor([[[[5.5210]]]], grad_fn=<MkldnnConvolutionBackward>) tensor(20.4391, grad_fn=<SumBackward0>)
3 tensor([[[[-3.4042]]]], grad_fn=<MkldnnConvolutionBackward>) tensor(19.3966, grad_fn=<SumBackward0>)
4 tensor([[[[823.6523]]]], grad_fn=<MkldnnConvolutionBackward>) tensor(676756.7500, grad_fn=<SumBackward0>)
5 tensor([[[[3.5471e+08]]]], grad_fn=<MkldnnConvolutionBackward>) tensor(1.2582e+17, grad_fn=<SumBackward0>)
6 tensor([[[[2.8560e+25]]]], grad_fn=<MkldnnConvolutionBackward>) tensor(inf, grad_fn=<SumBackward0>)
7 tensor([[[[inf]]]], grad_fn=<MkldnnConvolutionBackward>) tensor(inf, grad_fn=<SumBackward0>)
8 tensor([[[[nan]]]], grad_fn=<MkldnnConvolutionBackward>) tensor(nan, grad_fn=<SumBackward0>)
9 tensor([[[[nan]]]], grad_fn=<MkldnnConvolutionBackward>) tensor(nan, grad_fn=<SumBackward0>)
```

Why does my loss go to nan, and what can I do about it?

Comment: Have you tried running without normalization? Are you sure its bn?

Comment: @BedirYilmaz Yes, without batch normalization, this reliably produces near-zero loss. I will admit I did not test what happens without the fully-connected layer, though, hah!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to pytorch!

Here is how I would set up your training. Please check the comments.

```
# how the comunity usually does the import:
import torch  # some people do: import torch as th 
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    # setting some parameters:
    batch_size = 32
    n_dims = 128

    # select GPU if available
    device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'

    # initializing a simple neural net
    net = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(n_dims, n_dims  // 2), # Batch norm is not usually used directly on the input
                        nn.BachNorm1d(n_dims  // 2), # Batch norm is used before the activation function (it centers the input and helps make the dims of the previous layers independent of each other)
                        nn.ReLU(), # the most common activation function
                        nn.Linear(n_dims  // 2, 1)  # final layer)
    net.to(device) # model is copied to the GPU if it is availalbe

    optimizer = to.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.01) # it is better to start with a low lr and increase it at later experiments to avoid training divergence, the range [1.e-6, 5.e-2] is recommended.

    for i in range(10): 
       # generating random data:
       board = torch.rand([batch_size, n_dims])
       # for sequences: [batch_size, channels, L]
       # for image data: [batch_size, channels, W, H]
       # for videos: [batch_size, chanels, L, W, H]
       boad = board.to(device) # data is copied to the gpu if it is available

        optimizer.zero_grad()  # the convension the comunity uses, though the result is the same as net.zero_grad() 

        nn_outputs = net(board) # don't call net.forward(x), call net(x). Pytorch applies some hooks in the net.__call__(x) that are useful for backpropagation.

        loss = ((nn_outputs - 1)**2).mean() # using .mean() makes your training less sensitive to the batch size.

        print(i, nn_outputs, loss.item())

        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

One comment about the batch norm. Per dimension, it calculates the mean and the standard deviation of your batch (check the documentation https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BatchNorm2d.html#torch.nn.BatchNorm2d):

```
x_normalized = (x.mean(dim=0) / (x.std(dim=0) + e-6)) * scale + shift
```

Where scale and shift are learnable parameters. If you only give one example per batch, `x.std(0) = 0` will make `x_normalized` contain very very large values.

Comment: Where do you see the code you quoted at the end? I've been trying to dive through the source to find where `BatchNorm2d` actually bottoms out and having a bit of trouble (every  `batch_norm` just appears to call a different function named `batch_norm`!). But your description doesn't seem like it can possibly be right. I don't see very large values, like you predict. Additionally, `board.std(dim=0)` is a tensor-full of nans, not `0` as you claim; that would make me expect to get nan even at the very first iteration, but that's not what I see happening, either.

Comment: The code from the quite at the end is from the documentation, I edited the answer to add the link. The reason you get a tensor of `nan`s is probably because you are just giving one example to it!

Comment: I understand why `board.std(dim=0)` gives me a tensor of `nan`s. I do not (yet) understand why training my neural net gives sensible results for several iterations before blowing off to infinity (and then `nan`).

Comment: My first guess would be that it takes a few iterations before the weights of your network degenerate to `nan`s. If you try different learning rates, I would expect it to take longer for it to blow up if you use lower learning rates.

Answer (score 0):

For batch norm to be effective, you would like your training batches to be large.
In the case of 2d or 3d batch norm the "effective batch" includes the spatial/temporal dimensions of the feature map as well. In your example, you have `batch_size=1` and only 16 samples arranged spatially. This might be too little for batch norm to work effectively.
Try increasing the "effective batch size":

```py
board = t.rand([1, 1, 16, 16])
# or
board = t.rand([1, 16, 1, 16])
```

and see how this affects your training.

BTW, what happens in your toy example if you remove the batch norm?